# Where does Tolkien talk about hybridization of humans and other beings, in "On Fairy Stories"?

Tags: j-r-r-tolkien

Where does Tolkien talk about hybridization of humans and other beings, in "[On Fairy Stories](https://www.excellence-in-literature.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/fairystoriesbytolkien.pdf)"?

I just re-read it, and can't find the spot.

Is it just a small mention, related to the Frog Prince or something?

I got the info from [TVTropes's info on the essay](https://tvtropes.org/Literature/OnFairyStories), which says, or used to say:

> Heinz Hybrid: He mentions this, and notes that it can lead to unimpressive results if overdone.

Where [Heinz Hybrid](https://tvtropes.org/Laconic/HeinzHybrid) is:

> A hybrid of an implausible number of different species.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We cannot of course know the exact passage TV Tropes have in mind without asking the author, but I suspect it might be this.

> If men
> really could not distinguish between frogs and men, fairy-stories about frog-kings would not
> have arisen.

> Fantasy can, of course, be carried to excess. It can be ill done. It can be put to evil uses.

Comment: What's the exact source of this quote?

Comment: @Randal'Thor On Fairy Stories by Tolkein. Approx page 9 depending on printing.

Comment: Oops, I just saw the OP already mentioned a specific text. Sorry, I'm an idiot today.